# could not set the list property. Invalid property value error

Tags: vba, excel

I have e code the looks up for "!UKINADMISSIBLE" in column "M" of the sheet. then it displays all the selected rows Having "!UKINADMISSIBLE" in a list box (listbox1). it works well but if I delete all "!UKINADMISSIBLE" from the sheet it gives me this error (could not set the list property, Invalid property value) on this line of code---> **Me.ListBox1.List = arrLstBox()---> error**
Can anybody help me fix it please.

```
Private Sub btnIUK_Click()

Dim arrLstBox()
Dim rng, FoundCell, tmpCell As Range
Dim i, j, numRows, lastColumn, lastRow As Long
Dim FirstAddress, searchFor, colWidth As String

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
numRow = 0

With rng

    lastRow = .Rows.Count
    lastColumn = .Columns.Count

End With

Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = lastColumn
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "60;70;190;40;90;90;70;80;50;60;90;120;5"


    Set FoundCell = rng.Find(what:="!UKINADMISSIBLE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then _
    FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing

        Set FoundCell = rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then
            numRow = numRow + 1
            Exit Do
        ElseIf FoundCell.Row <> rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell).Row Then
            numRow = numRow + 1
        End If

ReDim arrLstBox(1 To numRow + 1, 1 To lastColumn + 1)

Loop

Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing

    For i = 1 To numRow
        For j = 1 To lastColumn

            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(FoundCell.Row, j).Value) Then

                arrLstBox(i, j) = Cells(FoundCell.Row, j).Value

            End If


        Next j

        Set FoundCell = rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then _
            Exit For

    Next i

    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then _
            Exit Do

Loop

Me.ListBox1.List = arrLstBox()----->ERROR

lastRow = ListBox1.ListCount
MsgBox "Records Found = " & lastRow, vb, "Inadmissibles On UK Sectors"

End Subode here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array is empty. In your code you should test for that and simply `Clear` the `ListBox` if it is the case.

Your code does seem a little inefficient. For example you are searching the entire document for an item you only wish to find in column M and you run the search twice. Why not search once only in column M and store the 'hit' rows in a variable? You could then simply populate the `ListBox` array with those rows. You might also consider sizing the `ListBox` columns just once in your `Userform_Initialize` event.

You should also be aware that most of your declarations are `Variants`. You have to declare each variable explicitly like this `Dim a As Integer, b As Integer`.

A skeleton code for this might look like something below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnIUK_Click()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim hits As Collection
    Dim hit As Variant
    Dim arrItems() As Variant

    'Read values into an array
    v = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value2

    'Find the target values
    Set hits = New Collection
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(i, 13) = "!UKINADMISSIBLE" Then hits.Add i
    Next

    'Populate the listbox array with the hit items
    If hits.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arrItems(1 To hits.Count, 1 To UBound(v, 2))
        i = 1
        For Each hit In hits
            For j = 1 To 13
                arrItems(i, j) = v(hit, j)
            Next
            i = i + 1
        Next
        Me.ListBox1.List = arrItems
    Else
        'There are not hits so clear the listbox
        Me.ListBox1.Clear
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 13
        .ColumnWidths = "60;70;190;40;90;90;70;80;50;60;90;120;5"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.
Just add elements to listbox if there's at least one cell in column M with searched value

Moreover if data to be added are always in columns A to M then you could both avoid counting columns and shift listbox settings to a `UserForm_Initialize` Sub.

Like this:

```
Private Sub btnIUK_Click()

Dim arrLstBox() As Variant
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, nCells As Long
Dim firstAddress As String

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet") '<--| always specify the worksheet name
    With .Range("M", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp)) '<--| consider column M cells down to its last non empty one
        nCells = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "!UKINADMISSIBLE") '<--| count searched value occurrences in column M
        If nCells > 0 then '<--| If there's at least one occurrence ...
            ReDim arrLstBox(1 To nCells, 1 To 13) '<--| ... ReDim your array...
            Set foundCell = .Find(what:="!UKINADMISSIBLE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| ...find first occurrence (it's there for sure!)
            firstAddress = foundCell.Address '<--| ...and store first occurrence address
            Do  '<--| first loop is granted! 
                i = i + 1 '<--| update array row index
                For j = 1 To 13 '<--| fill array row
                   arrLstBox(i, j) = foundCell.Offset(,-13 + j) '<--| use Offset from found cell to sta in its row and loop through columns 1 To 13
                Next
                Set foundCell = .FindNext (foundCell) '<--| look for subsequent occurrence
            Loop While firstAddress <> foundCell.Address '<--| subsequent loops are made till Find() wraps back to the first one
            Me.ListBox1.List = arrLstBox
        End If '<--| fill listbox
    End With 
End With 
MsgBox "Records Found = " & nCells, vb, "Inadmissibles On UK Sectors"

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 13
        .ColumnWidths = "60;70;190;40;90;90;70;80;50;60;90;120;5"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh yeah I messed up few code lines. thank you user3598756 for your time. well appreciated.